# How to get permutations from combinations?

Tags: combinatorics

A $5$-person committee is being formed to from $12$ teachers and $14$ students. How many ways can the committee be formed if at least one student and one teacher must be included?

---

The number of arrangements gives:
$12C1 * 14C1 * 24C3 = 340032$

While the correct approach of finding combinations gives:
$\binom{14}{1}\binom{12}{4}+\binom{14}{2}\binom{12}{3}+\binom{14}{3}\binom{12}{2}+\binom{14}{4}\binom{12}{1}=62986$ combinations/committees.

My question is how to derive the permutation based answer of $340032$ from $62986$.

Once formed a committee, there should be $5P5= 5!$ arrangements,  as no there is no condition to distinguish between members; but obviously failed.

It seems that the number of arrangements is not taken correctly as $\frac{340032}{62986}\approx {5.39}$

Comment: The first computation does not appear to be relevant.  If it is meant to be a solution to the problem, you are overcounting badly:  if, say, your group has $3$ teachers and $2$ students then you count it $10$ times, once for every pair of teacher and student.  The second solution is fine.

Comment: @lulu Please elaborate how am overcounting permutations. All I could gather is that for committee size of $5$, have $3C1.2C1.3C3= 6$. How factor of $10$ appears is unclear.

Comment: I have no idea what that means.  My point is simple.  The first (false) computation says "first pick a teacher, then pick a student, then pick $3$ more people from the remaining choices".  That overcounts.  Say your group is $\{T_1,T_2, T_3, S_1, S_2\}$.  then you get that group by first picking $T_1$, then picking $S_1$ and then picking $\{T_2, T_3, S_2\}$.  But you also get it if you first pick $T_2$ then pick $S_2$ and then pick $\{T_1, T_3, S_1\}$.  And so on.  There's no particularly useful way to salvage the computation, it's just wrong.

Comment: Ah, now I see what your  comment meant.  Yes, I made a mistake in writing $10$.  My example, $3$ teachers and $2$ students, is counted $3\times 2=6$ times, not $10$.

Comment: But, no.  There isn't a sensible way to fix the first computation.  My example was counted $6$ times, but a group consisting of $1$ teacher and $4$ students would be counted $1\times 4=4$ times, so you can't just divide to remove the overcounting.

Comment: @lulu So, might be my stated no. of arrangements are not correct. The actual number of arrangements can be then simply obtained from the correct number of combinations by multiplying by $5!$. But, this would then yield instead an even bigger number than $340032$.

Comment: i don't know what you mean by "arrangement" here.  The first computation is simply wrong, it doesn't compute anything terribly sensible.  I think it is a mistake to try to extract anything useful from it.

Comment: @lulu Request to make an answer that shows in more detailed manner the meaninglessness of the first computation to compute arrangements. By arrangements, I mean committees with orderings.

Comment: I have already done that.  Please review my comments.  For the first computation you are only partially considering orders.  Yes, you have a first teacher and a first student, but then the next three are chosen with no particular order.

Comment: If you are looking for an alternate way to solve the problem (besides your second computation), then just use Inclusion exclusion.  There are $\binom {26}5$ ways to choose the committee if you ignore the rule, so now just subtract the all teacher and the all student committees.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for your second last comment, so the only sensible (in terms of computation needed) method is to find the number of committees/combinations as in the second computation and multiply it by $5!$. Else, would take immense number of cases.

Comment: I gave you a simple alternative.  But I don't understand why you are suddenly introducing  an order to the committee.  Nothing in the problem requests you to order the committee and your second method does not consider an order.  But if you now want to introduce the order, then you can just multiply the number of unordered committees by $5!$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permutations and Combinations are entirely different. Here is another solution, if you were wondering.

We apply complementary counting. The total number of ways to choose 5 people from the group of 26 people (assuming that they are all distinct) is $\binom{26}{5}=65780$. We now subtract the number of ways to choose only students or only teachers which is $\binom{14}{5}+\binom{12}{5}=2794$. Thus, the answer is $65780-2794=\boxed{62986}$

It is very important to specify if they are distinct or indistinct.

Comment: Want to change to find # permutations (i.e., count lists rather than committees), but not possible now. For list counting better approach seems to get #combinations & multiply by $5!$. But, that would also include orderings in which the 2nd person in either category is selected before the first one. I mean if take as S1 first student, T1 first teacher. Then multiplying $62986$ by $5!$ would give wrong (i.e. say, an example case of S2S1T1T2T3) cases too. So, need find cases by fixing S1 before S2, S3, T2, T3. Similarly, for T1.